# python_ Simultaneously replace values in an array big or smaller than a threshold without using for-loop

Tags: python, arrays

### (Problem solved) The answer is as follow :

```
threshold=5
arr = np.arange(10)
new_array=[(1,num)[num>threshold] for num in arr]
new_array=[(0,num)[num<threshold] for num in new_array]
print(new_array)
```

---

I found the bug in my code below. It's obvious that arr turned to [1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,1] and then turned to [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0].

So I want to simultaneously replace values in an array big or smaller than a threshold without using for-loop.

I know I can use a for-loop to fix it. But i want it be concise. I can't find any alternative plan.

Here is the code I said ,although it's not the point.

```
import math
import numpy as np
def cont2disc(arr,threshold):
    total = arr.size
    tmp = arr
    index = math.floor(threshold*total)
    tmp.sort()
    boundary = tmp[index]
    arr[arr>=boundary] = 1
    arr[arr<boundary] = 0
    return(arr,index,boundary)

t = 0.5
c = np.arange(10)
print(c)
c,index,boundary = cont2disc(c,t)
print(c)
print(index)
print(boundary)
```

result:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
5
5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is still a for-loop based solution, If you want a it to be concise, I can suggest you this one liner:

```
new_array=[(0,num)[num>threshold] for num in arr]
```

This one liner will replace values smaller than `threshold` in your array with zeroes. For the other way around just change `num>threshold` to `num<threshold`.

Comment: Although it's not what I expected, but it still pretty concise. It's good enough to me.